# Hwo to change dynamically the last two parameteres?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have the followng string

`https://picsum.photos/id/1025/4951/3301`

I need to replace here the last two numbers 4951 and 3301 with 200 so at the end i will have
https://picsum.photos/id/1025/200/200

How can i do this automatically ?

**what i tried**

i tried to split them by '/'

```
 const splittedUrl = image.download_url.split('/');
  splittedUrl[splittedUrl.length - 1] = '200';
splittedUrl[splittedUrl.length - 2] = '200';
```

but it is not possible because i have `//` after https

so when i join it i get wrong output at the end

```
  console.log(splittedUrl.join(' '));
```

Comment: instead `splittedUrl.join(' ')` do `splittedUrl.join('/')`

Comment: I will have still problem because after https i have //

Comment: try the snippet I left you

Answer (score 1):

You are doing all good just instead join the string with empty string join with the `/`

```js
const stringVal = 'https://picsum.photos/id/1025/4951/3301';
const stringSplited = stringVal.split('/');



stringSplited[stringSplited.length - 1] = '200';
stringSplited[stringSplited.length - 2] = '200';


const stringJoined = stringSplited.join('/') 

//this will log the following: https://picsum.photos/id/1025/200/200
console.log(stringJoined)
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression replacement is designed for this sort of work.  A simple one which matches a `/` followed by some digits, followed by another `/`, some more digits, and the end of the string is `/\/\d+\/\d+$/`.  We can write it like this:

```js
const replaceLastTwos = (s1, s2) => (s) =>
  s .replace (/\/\d+\/\d+$/, `/${s1}/${s2}`)

const replaceLastTwoWith200s = replaceLastTwo (200, 200)

console .log (replaceLastTwoWith200 ('https://picsum.photos/id/1025/4951/3301'))
```

Of course if those `200`s are really fixed, you can simplify this to:

```js
const replaceLastTwoWith200s = (s) => s .replace (/\/\d+\/\d+$/, `/200/200`)
```